# Can I use a trademarked name in a project, if I don't own the trademark?

Tags: copyright, trademark, fair-use

I'm currently making a game, based on [Pokémon](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon).

I do not own the trademark, copyright, or anything legally related to Pokémon (just some rando on the net).

In my code, I use `Pokemon` to describe a specific idea; that a `Pokemon` is a unique member of a `Species` (`Pokemon:Species` as `Human:Homo sapiens sapiens`).

#### Examples:

- `PokemonService`: Holds a universally-unique identifier for a `Pokemon` (ie. `87628491-1246-4bc1-90cd-8b358f7a4f1c`)
- `PokemonStatService`: Holds any "stat" value associated with a `Pokemon` (ie. `{pokemon_id:87628491-1246-4bc1-90cd-8b358f7a4f1c,stat=Attack,value=10}`)
- `PokemonMoveService`: Holds any "move" associated with a `Pokemon` (ie. `{pokemon_id:87628491-1246-4bc1-90cd-8b358f7a4f1c,move=Tackle}`)

Would I be violating trademark, copyright, or something else if I have different constructs in my code that use the characters "Pokemon" to describe that construct?

Comment: To clarify: is this just in the source code, with no visibility to the user?

Comment: @DM really good question. I suppose the answer would be no, there would be references to "Pokemon" through different parts of the game (classification, "This is a fan-made Pokemon game", "I'm a Pokemon Professor", etc). Does the answer differ depending on that answer?

Comment: If nobody could see it because it was just in the code, then you likely wouldn't be using the trademark "in commerce", which is ordinarily required for infringement.

Comment: @DM This wouldn't be a game that I would be selling, a free (beer+freedom), GPLv3 game.

Comment: This may be relevant: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/12056/how-do-i-refer-to-a-trademark-i-dont-own-without-infringing-on-it?rq=1